# Creating an environment from an environment.yml file tqdm access is denied

Tags: python, pip, conda

I am trying to create an environment from an environment.yml file by running `conda env create -f environment.yml` in an administrator command prompt. The `environment.yml` file is as the following:

```
name: pytorch0.4
channels:
  - pytorch
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.6.5
  - pytorch=0.4.1
  - torchvision
  - numpy
  - nltk
  - ipython
  - docopt
  - pip
  - pip:
    - tqdm
```

After running the command, this error appeared:

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: \
Warning: 2 possible package resolutions (only showing differing packages):
  - defaults/noarch::parso-0.8.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0, defaults/win-64::jedi-0.17.0-py36_0
  - defaults/noarch::parso-0.7.0-py_0, defaults/win-64::jedi-0.17.2-py36haa95532done
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
Installing pip dependencies: - Ran pip subprocess with arguments:
['C:\\Users\\PC\\anaconda3\\envs\\pytorch0.4\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-U', '-r', 'C:\\Users\\Assignment\\A2\\a2\\condaenv.1tcu2wl4.requirements.txt']
Pip subprocess output:
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in c:\users\pc\anaconda3\envs\pytorch0.4\lib\site-packages (from -r C:\Users\Assignment\A2\a2\condaenv.1tcu2wl4.requirements.txt (line 1)) (4.56.0)
Collecting tqdm
  Using cached tqdm-4.58.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (73 kB)
Installing collected packages: tqdm
  Attempting uninstall: tqdm
    Found existing installation: tqdm 4.56.0
    Uninstalling tqdm-4.56.0:
      Successfully uninstalled tqdm-4.56.0

Pip subprocess error:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\PC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-uninstall-yeq37y9s\\tqdm.exe'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.


failed

CondaEnvException: Pip failed
```

I don't think my environment was created correctly, since I cannot use the dependencies in the environment nor activate it. I also tried to install `tqdm` by running `pip install tqdm --user`, it says that `Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in c:\users\pc\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (4.58.0)`. How do I initiate that environment then?

Comment: Conda doesn't play well with system- or user-level Python installations, and especially not with `--user` installations of packages. If you want well-defined behavior, you'll need to ensure Conda environments are isolated (e.g., get rid of that user-level Python).

Comment: Also, I don't follow the reason for installing `tdqm` using `pip`. Not only is it [available on **defaults** channel](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tqdm/files), but `nltk` explicitly depends on it, so it is definitely already getting installed through Conda. The whole ` - pip: ` section could be dropped.

Comment: @merv, could you write it as an answer? I will select it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conda should be able to solve this without resorting to `pip` since `tdqm` is available on the **defaults** channel. Moreover, `nltk` has `tdqm` as dependency, so the YAML could be simplified to

**File: pytorch0.4.yaml**

```yaml
name: pytorch0.4
channels:
  - pytorch
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.6.5
  - pytorch=0.4.1
  - torchvision
  - numpy
  - nltk
  - ipython
  - docopt
  - pip
```

Also, while using `pip` in Conda environments is valid, [it comes with some caveats](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#pip-in-env). One of these is to never use the `--user` flag, since this ends up placing packages outside the environment's `site-packages` and can lead to violating the isolation of environments that Conda is so keen on establishing.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "pyvenv.cfg" file in your Python project and change include-system-site-packages from false to true.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).